# What's are some best practices for building a site structure with multiple locations?

Tags: best-practice, sections

First time building a site with Craft, but a long time admirer.

Just wanted to know the best way to approach an educational site that has many locations,
and then have a news section, etc. in each one.

Not sure the best approach in regards to creating sections to achieve this.

Comment: "Best practice" and "Best way" questions are likely to be [closed](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions), as they are opinion-based.

Comment: @nicae how come the top voted question until now is one of these opinion based "best practice" questions?

Comment: @jon what do you mean with "multi locations"?

Comment: @jon Can you specify your question (have you tried sth. yet, have you specific concerns?...etc) or split it into multiple separate questions? Right now it's very broad and it's hard to give an answer without guessing.

Comment: @Christian Those questions definitely give something useful and not deleted if have high score, but [locked as having historical significance](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587). From help center: "... **primarily opinion-based** - discussions focused on diverse opinions are great, but they just don't fit our format well. Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than on facts, references, or specific expertise."

Comment: @Christian Consider [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/491595/2963652) question on Stack Overflow. Of course, good question, but off-topic. It was closed and locked by moderator and nothing can be changed in it.

Comment: Basically it's a site with static pages at the route, then 4 locations ie site/filton/ and then each of them will have pages of their own and a blog and other pages

Comment: Stack Overflow moderators != Craft SE moderators. I hope we won't ever close questions only because they have the words "best practice" in it!

Comment: @ChristianSeelbach Damn straight! Just trying to build it in a way that works the best

Comment: @jonleesmith I think this is a perfectly good question that couldn't hurt to be a bit more specific. (Welcome to SE and Craft, by the way!) For example, have you previously done something similar with WordPress or EE? Do you have an ideal plan that may (or may not) work ideally with Craft? Is the educational site about ice cream?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A different News Channel for each location:

For example:

- *News Location 1* with Entry URL Format `location-1/news/{slug}`
- *News Location 2* with Entry URL Format `location-2/news/{slug}`

Answer (score 2):

See this question: [Are there any intentions to release multisite support for Craft?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/408/are-there-any-intentions-to-release-multisite-support-for-craft/409#409) and be sure to click through to the G+ conversation

tl;dr: consider using locales. Custom locales likely to come to Craft somewhere down the road.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [mulit-environment](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/multi-environment-configs) config for your "locations" (if my guessing is right and you want different Base URLs). Both "locations" (= environments) get access to the same content.

Then you can access your site on:

- http://www.location-1.com
- http://www.location-2.com
- ...