# Switching to Craft from ExpressionEngine

Tags: craft-features

my client is looking to move away from ExpressionEngine. One of the reasons for this is that we are approaching the maximum number of sites we can run from MSM due to the limit on the number of columns we can create in MySQL for the data table.

Questions:

1. Managing Multiple Sites

   - Is it possible to run multiple sites using Craft?
   - Can you provide a login for users that would give them access to just their site?
   - Can you share content from the a global site across local sites?
2. Forms

   - Is there a plugin like Solspace Freeform for creating and managing forms?
3. Search

   - How does site searching work. Would there be a way to tie this in to display local sites only?

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You ask multiple questions at once – some of them quite broad. I'd recommend you create separate threads for each of your questions, and to try to be as specific as possible – e.g. elaborate a little on what you mean by "run multiple sites". That being said, in the event this thread isn't closed for being too broad I'll try to answer some of your main questions:

> Is it possible to run multiple sites using Craft?

Craft doesn't have an MSM-type feature, so short answer is no. [See this thread](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/408/are-there-any-intentions-to-release-multisite-support-for-craft) for some further details and alternative solutions.

> Is there a plugin like Solspace Freeform for creating and managing
>   forms?

Sure is. There's [Sprout Forms](https://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins/sprout-forms) which is a commercial, full-featured forms plugin, as well as a few free, smaller plugins such as [Form Builder](https://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins/form-builder).

> How does site searching work. Would there be a way to tie this in to display local sites only?

I'd suggest you look at the [official docs on searching](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/searching) in Craft, as well as the [example search form](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/search-form).

Comment: Thanks for your response, I believe that has answered my question(s)!

Answer (score 1):

About 1: Multi-site functionality is coming in Craft 3 (in public beta now), see [here](https://craftcms.com/news/craft-3-multi-site).