# Run a localized site using one Craft install on 2 servers

Tags: localization, multi-site

Is it possible to share one craft install across 2 servers?  Say I have a US site (en only) hosted in the US and a Canadian site (en and fr) hosted in Canada.

E.g.

```
usa-site.com (english)
ca-site.ca (english)
ca-site.ca/fr (french)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up having the ca-site.ca host all of the locales (`en_us`, `en_ca` and `fr_ca`).  The `en_us` locale was then set up to be a proxy for the usa-site.com site.  That way, it's easier to maintain the code base, as well as managing the content.

Craft's locale functionality is indeed amazing.  I do hope they come up with a solution that allows multi parent domain management.

@Matt P BTW thanks for the answer, I wanted to comment to it but rep is too low :)

Answer (score 2):

Craft has exceptional locale functionality, which would cater for your different languages.

See here for [relevant answer...](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/408/are-there-any-intentions-to-release-multisite-support-for-craft)

Besides the above, I understand that:

1. Multi-location/domain installation is not possible at the moment.
2. the licence for Craft applies to a domain. So for your example, each domain would require a separate Craft licence.

Comment: Actually, the license for Craft permits multi-domain use (as long as all the domains point to the same Craft installation). However, you're only allowed to access the _Control Panel_ on a single domain, per license. To that end, I've previously set up multi-domain Craft installs that redirect to the license-holding domain whenever a user attempts to access the Control Panel. [More info here](https://craftcms.com/support/license-enforcement#single-website-enforcement).

Comment: @MatsMikkelRummelhoff thanks for clarifying. That's really good to know!

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  Unfortunately I couldn't go with your solution as I have sites on completely different domains and hosts.